If מי יימר דדמך סומק טפי is true, and the same logic applies to property, then what about a property case where דמך סומק טפי?
The Talmud in Sanhedrin 74a states that if a Jew is forced to either forfeit his or her life or murder another, he or she must give up his or her life. The Talmud continues:

רוצח גופיה מנא לן סברא הוא דההוא דאתא לקמיה דרבה ואמר ליה אמר לי מרי
דוראי זיל קטליה לפלניא ואי לא קטלינא לך אמר ליה לקטלוך ולא תיקטול מי
יימר דדמא דידך סומק טפי דילמא דמא דהוא גברא סומק טפי


The Gemara asks: From where do we derive this halakha with regard to a murderer himself, that one must allow himself to be killed rather than commit murder? The Gemara answers: It is based on logical reasoning that one life is not preferable to another, and therefore there is no need for a verse to teach this halakha. The Gemara relates an incident to demonstrate this:


As when a certain person came before Rabba and said to him: The lord of my place, a local official, said to me: Go kill so-and-so, and if not I will kill you, what shall I do? Rabba said to him: It is preferable that he should kill you and you should not kill. Who is to say that your blood is redder than his, that your life is worth more than the one he wants you to kill? Perhaps that man’s blood is redder. This logical reasoning is the basis for the halakha that one may not save his own life by killing another.

By the same logic if one is forced to destroy his friend's property or forfeit his own property of equal value, he should forfeit his own - who says your property is more valuable than your friends? And if one is forced to either beat his friend or receive a similar beating, he should opt to receive the beating.
Do we find these parallel rules in Halacha?
Let's add a twist. Someone threatens you - destroy your friend's bottle of soda or I will destroy your house. What now?

Regarding property you can say whose property is more valuable - just assess its market price.

See Bava Kamma 60b אסור להציל עצמו בממון חבירו (referring to the slightly different case of damaging someone else's property in order to protect your life). See here for different interpretations of the rule

Who says your house is redder than his soda?

The way I understood it, is really by all mitzvos you dont give up your life, since vichai bahem ( you should live by them). The gemara said that logic to explain why this din doesn't apply to murder.
When it comes to any aveira a person is obligated to give up all his money not to do so. So if someone tells you to destroy someones property you would have to give up all your stuff not to do so. That logic cant permit you to do an aveira.
There might be other reasons why you would be allowed to distroy your friends stuff, maybe he would allow it to save your house etc..
But just because your property is more valuable wouldn't allow you to destroy your friends stuff. We dont see from the gemara that using that logic would allow a person to do an aveira.
